# Error in Merging two shape files (a spatial polygons and spatial points) in R

Tags: r, geospatial, spatial

My goal is to combine two shapefiles and extract the combined variables. However, I am getting the following error when I am trying to combine the two files: Error in as.vector(x): no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector

Below is my code:

```
#libraries
library(rgdal)
library(sp)
library(arulesViz)
library(rgdal)
library(raster)
library(maptools)

DHSshp <- readOGR("MWGE7AFL.shp")
district <- readOGR("mwi_admbnda_adm2_nso_20181016.shp")
summary(DHSshp)
summary(district)
is(DHSshp)
is(district)

subs_union <- union(DHSshp, district)
```

OR

```
pts.poly <- point.in.polygon(DHSshp, SAshp)
```

I failed to rule out that error after trying different ways around, I am hopeless. Please help

Comment: You should have a common field from `DHSshp` and `district` shapefile which may be district name. Then use `merged <- merge(district, DHSshp, by.x="NAME_1", by.y="NAME_2")`. Common field from DHSshp(NAME_2) and district shapefile (NAME_1) are NAME_1 and NAME_2.

Comment: Thank you, Bappa Das, for the response. But unfortunately, these two shapefiles have no common field. I overlayed DHS clusters from "DHSshp Shapefile" on the "district" shapefile. Now I need to allocate clusters to districts because I need to do the mapping at the district level, not cluster level. I am getting the above-mentioned error when I try to combine the two files.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this concern could be overcome by using the function
`point.in.poly()` of an r package 'SpatialEco',

i.e, use

```
SpatialEco::point.in.poly(DHSshp, district).
```

Regards!